# python pandas - remove duplicates in a column and keep rows according to a complex criteria

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this DF:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4])
s2 = pd.Series([10,20,10,5,10,7,7,3,10])
s3 = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,0])
df = pd.DataFrame([s1,s2,s3]).transpose()
df.columns = ['id','qual','nm']
df
   id  qual  nm
0   1    10   0
1   1    20   0
2   2    10   0
3   2     5   0
4   2    10   1
5   3     7   1
6   3     7   0
7   3     3   2
8   4    10   0
```

I want to get a new DF in which there are no duplicate ids, so there should be 4 rows with ids 1,2,3,4. The row that should be kept should be chosen based on the following criteria: take the one with smallest nm, if equal, take the one with largest qual, if still equal, just choose one.
I figure that my code should look something like:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: ???)
```

And it should return:

```
   id  qual  nm
0   1    20   0
1   2    10   0
2   3     7   0
3   4    10   0
```

But not sure what my function should take and return.
Or possibly there is an easier way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for minumum rows per groups, then for maximum values and last if still dupes remove them by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
#get minimal nm
df1 = df[df['nm'] == df.groupby('id')['nm'].transform('min')]
#get maximal qual    
df1 = df1[df1['qual'] == df1.groupby('id')['qual'].transform('max')]
#if still dupes get first id
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('id')
print (df1)
   id  qual  nm
1   1    20   0
2   2    10   0
6   3     7   0
8   4    10   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
grouper = df.groupby(['id'])
df.loc[(grouper['nm'].transform(min) == df['nm'] ) & (grouper['qual'].transform(max) == df['qual']),:].drop_duplicates(subset=['id'])
```

**Output**

```
   id  qual  nm
1   1    20   0
2   2    10   0
6   3     7   0
8   4    10   0
```